# Deleting from the outliner

Tags: outliner

Is there any way to set Blender to delete objects when I select them in the outliner and press delete? I tried assigning the shortcut in the right click menu, but that did not work either. It works when I delete a collection, I'd like to have the same behaviour when I select objects.

As you can see, it is supposed to be assigned to Delete button, but it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's missing from the Keymap, but you can add it manually. Go to Preferences>>Keymap>>Outliner. Click on Add New then type in outliner.id_delete for the identifier for the new item. Assign the Delete key or what you want and choose Any or Release for the press method, because for some reason it doesn't work with "Press". Now you will delete the item which below of the mouse cursor, not the selected.
[image]